# Get e-mail domain for admin in Magento 1.9 website

Tags: magento-1.9, email, domain

Lets say I have two magento websites, the first one is `www.magento-test.com` and the second one is `www.magentotest.com`. And lets say the e-mail for admin user for the first one is `john.doe@magento.com` and for the second one is `john.doe@magentotest.com`.

Is there a possible to get the e-mail domain? For example, for the first one I want `@magento.com` and for the second one I want `@magentotest.com`.

Comment: That admin email refers to some backoffice parameter? Or do you mean the admin user?

Comment: The e-mail from the admin user, exactly!

Comment: Ok, check answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, assuming your admin role has ID 1, you can check that browsing Backoffice, at **admin/permissions_role**

```
$adminRole = Mage::getModel('admin/roles')->load(1);
foreach ($adminRole->getRoleUsers() as $user){
    print_r(Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($user)->getData());
}
```